# SQL Server Agent job history to HTML report

Tags: html, sql-server, powershell, email, server

I am trying to output SQL Server Agent job history into an HTML report and send it to mail as a check in office.

Here's my code:

```
$tabName = "Report"

$table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable "$tabName"

$col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Server",([string])
$col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Job Name",([string])
$col3 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Step Name",([string])
$col4 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "Message",([string])
$col5 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn "RunDate",([string])

$table.columns.add($col1)
$table.columns.add($col2)
$table.columns.add($col3)
$table.columns.add($col4)
$table.columns.add($col5)

$data = (Get-SqlAgentJobHistory -ServerInstance SQLServ1 -JobName "syspolicy_purge_history" -Since Yesterday | Select-Object Server, JobName, StepName, Message, RunDate ) 
$row = $table.NewRow()

$row."Server" = ($data."Server")
$row."Job Name" = ($data."JobName")
$row."Step Name" = ($data."StepName")
$row."Message" = ($data."Message")
$row."RunDate" = ($data."RunDate")

$table.Rows.Add($row)

$Head = @"
 
<style>
  body {
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 8pt;
    color: #4C607B;
    }
  th, td {
    border: 1px solid #e57300;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 5px;
    }
  th {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #003366;
    color: #ffffff;
    }
  td {
    color: #000000;
    }
  .even { background-color: #ffffff; }
  .odd { background-color: #bfbfbf; }
</style>
 
"@

$Report = [string]$body = [PSCustomObject]$table | select-Object Server, JobName, StepName, Message, RunDate  | ConvertTo-HTML -head $Head -Body "<font color=`"Black`"><h4>SQL Job History</h4></font>"  | Out-File "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\scripts\sql job history\report.html"
```

The HTML fields I've added display when I output the report but not the content.

Any advise on this one please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `foreach` over the results from `Get-SqlAgentJobHistory`, eg

```
foreach ( $r in $data )
{
    $row = $table.NewRow()

    $row."Server" = ($r."Server")
    $row."Job Name" = ($r."JobName")
    $row."Step Name" = ($r."StepName")
    $row."Message" = ($r."Message")
    $row."RunDate" = ($r."RunDate")

    $table.Rows.Add($row)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. It sends an email with jobs information for the last 24 hours.

Just replace `'email_recipients_list'` and `'url_to_ssis_jobs_monitoring_report'` with relevant values.

```sql
DECLARE 
    @email_recipients VARCHAR(128)
    , @email_subject NVARCHAR(128)
    , @email_body_format VARCHAR(128)
    , @email_body NVARCHAR(MAX)
    , @job_count INT
    , @table_style VARCHAR(512)
    , @from datetime
    , @periode NVARCHAR(512)
    , @url_to_ssis_jobs_monitoring_report VARCHAR(128)

SET @email_recipients='email_recipients_list'
SET @email_body_format='HTML'
SET @table_style = 'cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1"  style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid black;"';
SET @from = DATEADD(day, -1, getdate())
SET @periode = 'between ' + FORMAT(DATEADD(d, -1, GETDATE()), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss') + ' and ' + FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss') 
SET @email_subject = 'SSIS Jobs ' + @periode
SET @url_to_ssis_jobs_monitoring_report = 'url_to_ssis_jobs_monitoring_report'

DECLARE @job_table NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @job TABLE(
    [Start time] NVARCHAR(19)
    , [Job] NVARCHAR(128)
    , [Job execution status] NVARCHAR(128)
    , [Execution time] NVARCHAR(8)
);

WITH subset As (
    SELECT
        CAST(left(t1.run_date,8) As DATETIME) + CAST(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000'+ISNULL(CAST(t1.run_time As NVARCHAR(6)),''),6),5,0,':'),3,0,':') As datetime) As [Start time]
        , t1.job_id As 'Id Job'
        , t1.name As Job
        , CASE IIF(MIN(t2.run_status) = 1, MAX(t2.run_status), MIN(t2.run_status))
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Succeeded'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'In Progress'
            ELSE 'Unknown'
        END As [Status]
        , CONVERT(TIME(0), DATEADD(SECOND, 
            SUM(
                DATEDIFF(SECOND,0,CAST(CAST(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000'+ISNULL(CAST(t2.run_duration As NVARCHAR(6)),''),6),5,0,':'),3,0,':') As TIME) As DATETIME))
            )
            , 0)
        ) As 'Execution time'

    FROM (
        SELECT
            sjh.job_id
            ,sj.name As name
            ,sjh.run_date
            ,sjh.run_time 
            ,LEAD(sjh.run_time,1) OVER ( ORDER BY run_date, run_time) As next_run_time
            ,MIN(sjh.run_status) As run_status
        FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobhistory] sjh
        LEFT JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] sj
            ON sjh.job_id = sj.job_id
        WHERE
            sjh.step_id = 1
            -- To exclude unrelevant jobs
            AND TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,sj.name) IS NULL

        GROUP BY sjh.job_id, sj.name, sjh.run_date, sjh.run_time
    ) t1
    LEFT JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobhistory] t2
        ON 
            t2.job_id = t1.job_id 
            AND t2.run_date = t1.run_date 
    WHERE 
        t2.job_id = t1.job_id 
        AND t2.run_date = t1.run_date 
        AND t2.step_id <> 0
        AND CAST(left(t1.run_date,8) As datetime) + CAST(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000'+ISNULL(CAST(t1.run_time As NVARCHAR(6)),''),6),5,0,':'),3,0,':') As datetime) > @from 
        -- To exclude unrelevant jobs
        AND TRY_CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,t1.name) IS NULL
    GROUP BY t1.job_id,  t1.run_date, t1.run_time, t1.name, t1.next_run_time
)

INSERT INTO @job
SELECT 
    FORMAT(s.[Start time], 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss') As [Start time]
    , s.Job
    , s.Status
    , CAST(s.[Execution time] As NVARCHAR(8)) As [Execution time]
FROM subset s


SET @job_count = @@ROWCOUNT

If @job_count > 0
BEGIN

    SET @job_table = CAST( (
    SELECT td = [Start time] + '</td><td>' + [Job] + '</td><td>' + [Job execution status] + '</td><td>' + [Execution time]
    FROM (
          SELECT *
          FROM @job
          ) As d
    ORDER BY [Start time]

    FOR XML PATH( 'tr' ), TYPE ) As NVARCHAR(MAX) )

    set @job_table = '<table ' + @table_style + '>'
              + '<tr><th>Start time</th><th>Job</th><th>Job execution status</th><th>Execution time</th></tr>'
              + replace( replace( @job_table, '&lt;', '<' ), '&gt;', '>' )
              + '</table>'

    SET @email_body = @job_table

END

SET @email_body = '<h1>SSIS Jobs ' + @periode + '</h1>' + @email_body

SET @email_body = @email_body + '<br><br><a href="url_to_ssis_jobs_monitoring_report">SSIS jobs monitoring report</a>'

-- Send email
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
    @recipients=@email_recipients
    , @body=@email_body 
    , @subject=@email_subject
    , @body_format=@email_body_format
```